# Create custom shipping method in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to add my custom shipping method using Bigcommerce API. I don't want to use any of the pre-existing methods such as flat rate, free shipping, FedEx, Australia post etc.

I have gone through their API, especially shipping resources, but it doesn't seem any methods are available to add our own shipping method.

Shipping resource API documentation
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/shipping/methods#get-shipping-method

I don't even know do we need special permission fro Bigcommerce guys to add shipping method.
Please help if anybody has developed or trying to develop similar thing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I need to integrate third party shipping calculator to bigcommerce site. First thing is that bigcommerce is a hosted solution which means that we don't have direct access to their code via ftp. So we can't modify the code to add our shipping calculator.

2nd thing is that they do not allow any unsupported thirdy party gateways or softwares.
Read this
https://support.bigcommerce.com/?page=support_policy

They say that:

### Unsupported Gateways and Third Party Software

We are not able to support any third party gateways or third party software we do not integrate with. We are unable to provide any "How to use", modify or extend the use of any third party software outside of any documentation we've provided.

Also note that bigcommerce API is not for this purpose. It comes in use when someone wants to pull data from bigcommerce shop via its api. You are looking at this in reverse direction which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I asked their API support team they replied me that at this moment they are not allowing any other third party shipping method using their API. So clearly there is no way to do add our own custom shipping method.